# Why my for jump some terms after remove ? [Python]

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new with python language and I'm having trouble to understand why this code doesn't work as I expect.
I want to calculate and put in a tuple the primitive pythagorean triplet (a^2+b^2=c^2) for a,b,c < 100.
This is the code

```
n=100
#Here I calculate all the pythagorean triples and I put it in a list(I wanted to use the nested list comprehension)
d=[(ap,b,c) for ap in range(1,n+1) for b in range(ap,n+1) for c in range(b,n+1)  if ap**2 +   b**2 == c**2  ]
#it work
#now I wonna find the primitive one: 
q=[]
for q in d: #I take each triples 
    #I check if it is primitive
    v=2       
    for v in range(2,q[0]) : 
        if q[0]%v==0 and q[1]%v==0 and q[2]%v== 0 :
            d.remove(q)  #if not I remove it and exit from this cycle
            break
#then I would expect that it read all the triples, but it doesn't
#it miss the triples after the one I have cancelled
```

Can you tell me why?
Is there another way to solve it?
Do I miss some step ?

Comment: You don't need to add `break` after removing the first one. `break` exits the loop, that's why *it miss the triples after the one you have cancelled*. Remove the `break`

Comment: Don't remove items from a list while you are iterating over it

Comment: Just change the first for loop to `for q in list(d):` and then you can remove items from `d`, because the for loop is now iterating over a copy of `d`.

Comment: Thank you barny, now it work!

Comment: Shivam if I removed the break it gave me the error : list.remove(x): x not in list

Answer (score 1):

The missing 3-tuples are not caused by the **break** but by modifying a list at the same time that you loop it. When you remove an element from a list, the remaining element's indexes is also modified, which can produce a loop to skip certain elements from being checked. It's never a good practice to remove elements from a list you are iterating. One usually create a copy of the list that you iterate, or use functions such as **filter**.

Also, you can remove `v = 2`. There's no need to set the value of **v** to 2 for every iteration when you already do so with the instruction `for v in range(2,q[0])`

**Iterating over a copy of d**

If you do **list(d)** then you create a clone of the list you are iterating. The original list can be modified but it won't be a problem because your loop will always iterate over the original list.

```
n=100
d=[(ap,b,c) for ap in range(1,n+1) for b in range(ap,n+1) for c in range(b,n+1)  if ap**2 + b**2 == c**2]
q=[]
for q in list(d):
    for v in range(2,q[0]) :
        if q[0]%v==0 and q[1]%v==0 and q[2]%v== 0 :
            d.remove(q)
            break
```

**Use the function filter**
For the [**filter** function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) , you need to define a function that is applied to every element of your list. The **filter** function uses that defined function to build a new list with the elements that pass. If the defined function returns **True** then that element is kept and used for the new list, if it returns **False**, then that element is not used. **filter()** returns an iterator, so you need to build the list from it.

```
def removePrimitives(q):
    for v in range(2, q[0]):
        if q[0] % v == 0 and q[1] % v == 0 and q[2] % v == 0:
            return False
    return True

n=100
d=[(ap,b,c) for ap in range(1,n+1) for b in range(ap,n+1) for c in range(b,n+1)  if ap**2 + b**2 == c**2]
q=[]
d = list(filter(removePrimitives, d))
```

**Bonus: debugging**

When it comes to coding, no matter what language, I believe one of the first things you should learn to do is how to debug it. Python has an **amazing** interactive debugging module called: ipdb.

Here's the commands:

```
n[ext]:         next line, step over
s[tep]:         step into next line or function.
c[ontinue]:     continue
l[ine]:         show more lines
p <variable>:   print value
q[uit]:         quit debugging
help:           show all commands
help <command>: show help
```

Install the package with your **pip installer**. Here's how you could have used it in your code to see exactly what happens when a primitive tuple is found and you break from the inner loop:

```
import ipdb
n=100
d=[(ap,b,c) for ap in range(1,n+1) for b in range(ap,n+1) for c in range(b,n+1)  if ap**2 +   b**2 == c**2  ]
q=[]
for q in d:
    for v in range(2,q[0]) :
        if q[0]%v==0 and q[1]%v==0 and q[2]%v== 0 :
            ipdb.set_trace() # This sets the breakpoint
            d.remove(q)
            break
```

At this breakpoint you can print the variable **q**, and **d**, and see how it gets modified and what happens after the **break** is executed.